# What are the places that sell coffee beans called in Turkey?

Tags: food-and-drink, turkey, istanbul

What should I search for on the google maps for such a store; I already tried "kahve çekirdekleri" and "kahve" but the results seem to be mere coffee shops.

I'm in the Beylikduzu zone in Istanbul.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNT4Od43js8JLuw5rcMqmJ8Xagfz7Q%3A1571122000013&ei=UGulXeAzxLutAebuptgO&q=sell+coffee+beans+istanbul&oq=sell+coffee+beans+istanbul&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30.5433.6357..6619...0.3..0.329.2054.2-7j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i8i67.Z83iIZCIzX0&ved=0ahUKEwjgm9bF1Z3lAhXEXSsKHWa3CesQ4dUDCAo&uact=5 - looks like a few come recommended on google

Comment: @Mark Mayo thanks; i tried it; but the results are either too far like 1 hour away on the other sides of city or are coffee shops; i think im just not searching for the right term. how can it be that large parts of a city has no coffee beans distribution? there must be a more explanatory term.

Comment: @kamyar it seems supermarkets and cafes like Starbucks have the majority of bean sales, unless you go to specialty shops like Kronotrop or the spice market

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for "Kurukahveci" or "Kurukahvecisi", which is "seller of coffee beans or ground coffee" or "coffee store".

The most popular "Kurukahveci" is [Kurukahveci Mehmet Efendi](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g293974-d8570899-Reviews-Kurukahveci_Mehmet_Efendi-Istanbul.html), which is pretty far (approx. 35 km) from the Beylikduzu zone in Istanbul, for coffee beans. It's just outside the spice market.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is **Çekilmemiş Kahve**. You should be able to find some in your local [Migros](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Migros/@41.0066851,28.6574202,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x4317b94bdb555b06?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrt5vh4p_lAhUThuYKHX_vA1gQ_BIwDXoECAgQCA). They have different types of Çekilmemiş Kahve, and the prices will be relatively cheaper than if you were to go to the [Grand Bazaar](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurant_Review-g293974-d795490-Reviews-Kahve_Dunyasi_Nuruosmaniye-Istanbul.html).

If you're solely after Turkish coffee beans, you could try for **çekilmemiş turk kahvesi** from places like [Kahve Dunyasi](https://www.kahvedunyasi.com/cok-kavrulmus-turk-kahvesi-cekirdek-1kg-p-14).

Comment: thanks for the name. i've tried migros. they have packet coffee and most of them are Turkish powder in very low variety;

Answer (score 2):

As others say, the term is Kurukahveci. However many won't appear on Web searches. Just go to the Spice Bazaar and Grand Bazaar for the easiest options.

Answer (score -2):

Like most other places across the world, they are called Starbucks ;)  There are lots of them in Istanbul.  There's one near Taksim Square

And another, close to you in Beylikdüzü.

Comment: Do you have any indication that they sell beans as well as ready to drink coffee? I think that information is way more important than photos of their fronts (which have not been given a good source, by the way.)

Comment: The request was for what to search for on google maps and the source of the photos was google maps. Starbucks always sells beans as well as coffee ready to drink. That seems like a relevant answer.  You can look at inside photos for any of those Starbucks on google maps and find pictures of beans in bags for sale. The down vote seems a bit harsh. If you've never been in a Starbucks then you should visit one and see for your self. Enjoy!

Comment: I have not downvoted, but you can not assume that everybody knows a 'ready to drink' company also sells beans, that should have been in your answer, not a pic of the outsides.